# Display GUID column of document in the XML Api request

Tags: list, document-library, column, xml, guid

Before I start, let me just say that I have no experience with Sharepoint. Because of this I do not have the necessary knowledge of the different terminology, so bare with me.
That said, I'm currently working on a project in which our client has a Sharepoint server which delivers a XML file(RSS) with a list of documents (`http://MySite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyList`). We created our own Sharepoint server for testing purposes which also returns a similar XML file.
Every `<entry></entry>` tag contains a list of 
`<m:properties xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">`
which resemble the columns I select in the Document Library Settings List page.
Now my question is, how can I add the (Document)GUID column to the properties list? (the GUID column is not available from the "add from existing site columns" page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by using the unique document IDs instead of GUIDs. 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-unique-document-ids-HA101790471.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to get the list data as XML, may be that help you.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx[enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/05/01/getting-xml-data-from-a-sharepoint-list-the-easy-way.aspx)

Comment: Stop posting link-only answers! When the link breaks, your answer will be of no help to future readers!

Comment: This does not solve my problem, since this is a different representation of data. I need to change the data it returns.